# neo4j EntityNotFound prevents cypher match from working

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My neo4j db is in a corrupted state. A former node, also a Person node connected to a State via Address, prevents any matches from working:

```
match (p:Person)--(:Address)--(s:State) where s.name="Cali" return p, s

  Node with id 101005

  Neo.ClientError.Statement.EntityNotFound
```

I suspect this is something to do with the 101005 node still existing in the label index even though it's been deleted.

How do I recover without clearing all of the data? I've deleted all of the Person relationships/nodes and reloaded them to no avail. Using a different label ("Persons") doesn't help either.

Ubuntu, Neo4j 2.0.0 M06 when created and now on 2.0.0 stable, using cypher in the browser.

Thanks.

Edit:

Previously, when deleting other nodes, the query timed out and the db went unresponsive with a heap space exception in the logs:

```
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Statistics Gatherer[primitives]"
08:35:29.207 [qtp1069006536-4036] WARN  o.e.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler - Error for /db/data/transaction/commit
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Comment: Has anything happened to your data to make you suspect that the database is corrupt? I can't find any documentation on when `EntityNotFound` is thrown exactly.

Comment: Yeah, I did a large delete of some other nodes and the query timed out, the db went unresponsive, and I had to restart it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you see / check the manual update procedure from M06 to RC1 / 2.0-Final?

See: http://blog.neo4j.org/2013/11/neo4j-200-rc1-final-preparations.html

### Caution: manual upgrade between milestones

Data stores created with any previous milestone version can not be used with 2.0.0-RC1 unless a manual upgrade is performed. This is due to incompatible changes made to the store files. Please proceed with caution, backing up your data before attempting to manually upgrade.

#### Manual upgrade (only from 2.0.0-M06, and after you've backed up):

***Cleanly shut down on the old version on Neo4j 2.0.0-M06***

- bin/neo4j stop

Navigate to the database directory

- cd data/graph.db

Delete the label scan store (this is the critical part that has a new format). It will be recreated on startup.

- rm -rf schema/label

Start with the new version of Neo4j 2.0.0-RC1

- bin/neo4j start