# EntityNotFound during query for all instances of two related types

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

#### Background

We are using Spring Data Neo4j over HTTP driver. We are using Neo4j 3.2 Docker image.

We have three node types including Label (aka tag) and Project, where each project node can be linked to multiple label nodes and vice versa.

#### Query

I'm performing the following query through GraphRepository:

```
@Query("MATCH (label:Label)-[]-(project:Project)"
       + "RETURN (label:Label)-[]-(project:Project)")
public Iterable<Label> findAllWithProjects() throws CypherException;
```

Which returns all Project nodes along with their linked Label nodes.

#### Problem

I get the following error:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.neo4j.ogm.exception.CypherException: Error executing Cypher "Neo.ClientError.Statement.EntityNotFound"; Code: Neo.ClientError.Statement.EntityNotFound; Description: Unable to load NODE with id 1207.] with root cause
org.neo4j.ogm.exception.CypherException: Error executing Cypher "Neo.ClientError.Statement.EntityNotFound"; Code: Neo.ClientError.Statement.EntityNotFound; Description: Unable to load NODE with id 1207.
```

The problem is occurring on a production system. The same query used to work before, and it currently works on development and staging environments.

#### Troubleshooting

1. I deleted `schema/label` folder as advised in post [neo4j EntityNotFound prevents cypher match from working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173724/neo4j-entitynotfound-prevents-cypher-match-from-working) but that didn't help.
2. I executed the same query on production server using HTTP POST to neo4j server and it seems to work.
3. I tried to look up the node using `http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/1207` but it returns 404 Not Found.
4. I tried deleting that node from my application, but again its not found. I also executed delete all relations to that node, using multiple queries like:

   ```
   MATCH (label:Label)-[r:LABELED_PROJECTS]-(project:Project)
   WHERE id(project) = 1207
   DELETE r
   ```

   I executed a few of these queries with different types of nodes (with id=1207) and returns, but all of them returned empty result.
5. I adjusted the query adding a condition as follows and that makes it work from the application:

   ```
   MATCH (label:Label)-[]-(project:Project)
   WHERE NOT id(project) = 1207
   RETURN (label:Label)-[]-(project:Project)
   ```